# Time Complexity of C++ string append - string1 += string2;

Tags: c++, string, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of the following piece of code given that s1 is a string of length l1 and s2 is a string of length l2.

```
s1 += s2;
```

My timing tests show O(l2). However the C++ specification is not very clear on this.

Comment: Question like this can be easily looked up on cppreference.  For example [`std::string::operator+=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D)

Comment: I guess it must be O(l1+l2), because a new allocation may be needed and everything copied. That's worst case.

Comment: It is not very clear here - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+= 
@NathanOliver . It says `Unspecified, but generally up to linear in the new string length.` Yes it is clear in your link, thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for a Standard quote that explains this?  I expected to find something in [**string.append**](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/string.append), but nothing. Probably hidden away in sequence containers or iterators.

Comment: @Satu0King cplusplus.com is kind of garbage.  cppreference is much better IMHO and more accurate.

Comment: @NathanOliver I didn't know! Thank You I will refer that from next time.

Comment: Make this an answer, it's more believable than cppreference's stated complexity.

Comment: Cppreference's is usually better but right hand size length complexity is not possible.

Comment: @Jeffrey what do you mean by *this* in *Make this an answer*?

Comment: I believe it is amortized to right hand size length complexity. (like vectors) @Jeffrey

Answer (score 3):

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D) is pretty specific.

Time complexity of `operator +=` is linear in size of right-hand side operand.

Comment: That can't be right. Re-allocation can be needed. In this case, the sum of lengths would be needed.

Comment: I believe it is amortized to right hand size length complexity. (like vectors) @Jeffrey

Comment: @Satu0King Fair enough. IMO, it should definitely be stated "amortized". Personally, I buy it for vector resize, but here I find it stretch.

Comment: Why do you find it a stretch here? Strings in C++ also have a capacity() member, and generally speaking that capacity is larger than the size of the string itslf

Answer (score 1):

even if the capacity were to be 10000, on that 10000th insertion there would be a reallocation of double the current capacity, still converging to O(n)